# Data field null value return 0

Tags: php, sql-server

I am storing a radio button value which can be true, false or NULL in a database. 
In case of null or false the answer is 0 that is false. 
Is there any solution for checking the null value? I have tried using isset and Empty but none of these help.
Database is MSSQL and datatype is bit to store the value of radio button

```
<input name="radioVal" type="radio" id="radioVal" value="false"
<?PHP
           if(row['radioVal'] == false ) 
              echo "checked='checked' "; 
}
?> />

<input name="radioVal" type="radio" id="radioVal" value="true"
<?PHP
           if(row['radioVal'] == true ) 
              echo "checked='checked' "; 
}
?> />
```

Comment: Try using the `===` operator, and see if that works. Otherwise, try a `var_dump($row)` and see exactly what you're being passed.

Comment: I have tried var_dump and it returns int(0) on null.. :(...
Is it problem with mssql server?? In database it is showing null at least.

Answer (score 1):

TRY

```
 if(false === row['radioVal'] ) //or
 if(NULL === row['radioVal'] )
```

and to check for NULL you can check with [is_null](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.is-null.php)

```
 is_null(row['radioVal'])
```

Comment: @Echo I have tried with ===   and 
 0 === row['radioVal']    returns 1 on   false
                          returns 1 on   NULL 
                          returns empty on true
 NULL === row['radioVal']  
                          returns 1 on false and NULL 
                          returns empty on true
where as is_null returns empty in all three cases

Answer (score 1):

The bit column is probably going to be represented as a `1` or a `0`. Use the triple equals to check for value *and* type. Check if `row['radioVal'] === 1` for true, `row['radioVal'] === 0` for false, and `row['radioVal'] === null` for null.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you should use another data type in your SQL Database.

I suggest Enum or something like that:

```
ENUM('false', 'true', 'NULL')
```

In your PHP file you

```
<?PHP
       if(row['radioVal'] == false ) 
          echo "checked='checked' "; 
}
?>
```

Comment: I'm struggling to find an enum in SQL Server except ways to get around it (CLR). Any reference?

Comment: AFAIK there is no enum type in MSSQL (as you state there are ways like check / foreign key)

Comment: Thinking of something like enum or using short insted and make three values.